# error C2373: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different type modifiers

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm on working on someone's else code which is written for some socket programming. This project has following two files.

**SOCKUTIL.H**

```
#if !defined(SOCKUTIL_H)
#define SOCKUTIL_H

unsigned long   inet_addr(const char *sIp);

unsigned short  htons(unsigned short port);
#endif
```

**sockUtil.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sockutil.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long inet_addr(const char *sIp)
{
    int             octets[4];
    int             i;
    const char      *auxCad = sIp;
    unsigned long   lIp = 0;

    //we extract each octet of the ip address
    //atoi will get characters until it found a non numeric character(in our case '.')
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        octets[i] = atoi(auxCad);

        if(octets[i] < 0 || octets[i] > 255)
        {
            return(0);
        }

        lIp |= (octets[i] << (i * 8));

        //update auxCad to point to the next octet
        auxCad = strchr(auxCad, '.');

        if(auxCad == NULL && i != 3)
        {
            return(0);
        }

        auxCad++;
    }

    return(lIp);
}

unsigned short htons(unsigned short port)
{
    unsigned short  portRet;

    portRet = ((port << 8) | (port >> 8));

    return(portRet);
}
```

This project originally was developed in VC6 and when I opened it in VS2013, Visual studio converted it. But when I *build* it, then it is giving following errors.

> error C2373: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different type modifiers
>
> error C2373: 'htons' : redefinition; different type modifiers

I tried to find solution, but didn't get what to do. I don't have much knowledge on it.

Edit: This code doesn't use **#include Winsock2.h**. I checked few online solutions available which claims that this library is the reason for redefinition but this is not true in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions are already defined for you in more recent versions of Visual Studio (see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx)) - you can just remove these files from your project and remove all occurrences of:

```
#include "sockutil.h"
```